# The UserObjectID is not visible in the logs for some records in the Azure Log Analytics Workspace

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

The UserObjectId is not showing for some of the Records in the Azure Blob Storage Logs. I have configured all the settings(Diagnostic Settings and Diagnostic Settings(Classic)) but I am not able to see the Object ID's for some Records. I have also enabled the Log 2.0 logs in the Diagnostic Settings. Here is a link to the Log Format for Azure Blobs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-log-format

I have tried searching and reading various Azure Documentations but I am unable to see the Object IDs of people in the Logs who performed an operation on the blobs in my Storage Account.

Comment: Please provide more information about the records you are mentioning? If you add a screenshot, it will be informative.

Comment: @Imran I have followed these documentations and configured the settings in my Storage Account accordingly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-log-format and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/manage-storage-analytics-logs?tabs=azure-portal